# Javascript - InnerHTML doesn't edit the DOM

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I'm working on a project with Laravel. Now I'm coding the feature which prints all activities responsible. Before I was using `foreach` loop in  PHP to print all of my activities (from the DB).

But now I have to use JS to print these activities because I want to add a filter (and avoid page to reload).

I have created this script in my view :

```
 <script>
                containerE = document.getElementById("container");
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open("GET","{{route('APIManifs')}}", false);
                request.send(null);

                responses = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                function expandResults(value){
                    for (var i in responses){
                        if (responses[i].status === value) {

                            containerE.innerHTML = containerE.innerHTML +
                                "<div class=\'col-md-5 offset-1\' id=\'1\'>" +
                                "<div class=\'card\'>" +
                                "<a href='/manif/" + responses[i].id + "'"+" ><div class=\'card-header\' style=\'text-align: center\'>"+
                                "<img src='"+responses[i].image+"'><br>"+
                                responses[i].name+" | "+responses[i].date_add+"<br>"+
                                "</div> </a>"+
                                "<div class=\'card-body\'>"+
                                "Nom : "+responses[i].name+"<br>"+
                                "Description : "+responses[i].description+"<br>"+
                                "</div>"+
                                "</div>"+
                                "</div>";
                            containerE.innerHTML = containerE.innerHTML + "Arg";
                            console.log(responses[i].status+"=="+value);
                        }
                        else{
                            console.log(responses[i].status+"<>"+value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            </script>
```

I got the information but impossible to print my HTML in the DOM! When I copy paste the inner HTML code in the console it's work.

Do you have any ideas on how to accomplish this?
Thank's in advance!

Comment: Have you confirmed that your function `expandResults` is actually being _called_ anywhere?  I see it defined in your code, but never invoked.

Comment: I assume the `console.log` is working so you are getting logs saying it has found a matching value?

Comment: @AlexanderNied : It's call in my select list : 
 <select onchange="expandResults(this.value);" class="form-control" id="sell" name="manifStatus">

Comment: @Rhumborl Yes indeed, i used consol.log to debug it. It's work well. Just innerHTML doesn't edit the DOM

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem? Replace the AJAX call with hard-coded data.

Comment: @Barmar :
I did the Minimal code and it's working (Sorry i can't post it here the limit is too short...) It's doesn't work in fault of the function expandResults. When i delete it and let the loop for run alone it's work. Why ?????

Comment: If you can't post it here, can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Yep ! This is this link : https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=6pmcGTAGzK

I know why : the request can't be send before execute the function. If the function contain the request it's work well ! But that's boring because users will have to send request each time and it's not optimized ....